# Como validar CPF com DataAnnotation no Cliente e Servidor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dataannotations

Preciso validar CPF com `Data Annotation`, e verificar se há duplicidade.

Comment: Eu usaria o remote no model para buscar de outro lugar ao invés de colocar lógica no model, mas aí vai de cada um.

Comment: Remote faz request para uma validação que você poderia fazer na View ? Conforme a resposta do @iuristona

Answer (score 21):

Primeiramente, crie uma classe que será o Custom Validation Attribute. O código da classe será o seguinte:

```
/// <summary>
/// Validação customizada para CPF
/// </summary>
public class CustomValidationCPFAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Construtor
    /// </summary>
    public CustomValidationCPFAttribute() { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Validação server
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
        return true;

        bool valido = Util.ValidaCPF(value.ToString());
        return valido;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Validação client
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="metadata"></param>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(
        ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        yield return new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = this.FormatErrorMessage(null),
            ValidationType = "customvalidationcpf"
        };
    }
}
```

O código da classe Util, que possui o método que faz a validação do CPF é o seguinte:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Remove caracteres não numéricos
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string RemoveNaoNumericos(string text)
    {
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"[^0-9]");
        string ret = reg.Replace(text, string.Empty);
        return ret;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Valida se um cpf é válido
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cpf"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool ValidaCPF(string cpf)
    {
        //Remove formatação do número, ex: "123.456.789-01" vira: "12345678901"
        cpf = Util.RemoveNaoNumericos(cpf);

        if (cpf.Length > 11)
            return false;

        while (cpf.Length != 11)
            cpf = '0' + cpf;

        bool igual = true;
        for (int i = 1; i < 11 && igual; i++)
            if (cpf[i] != cpf[0])
                igual = false;

        if (igual || cpf == "12345678909")
            return false;

        int[] numeros = new int[11];

        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
            numeros[i] = int.Parse(cpf[i].ToString());

        int soma = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            soma += (10 - i) * numeros[i];

        int resultado = soma % 11;

        if (resultado == 1 || resultado == 0)
        {
            if (numeros[9] != 0)
                return false;
        }
        else if (numeros[9] != 11 - resultado)
            return false;

        soma = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            soma += (11 - i) * numeros[i];

        resultado = soma % 11;

        if (resultado == 1 || resultado == 0)
        {
            if (numeros[10] != 0)
                return false;
        }
        else
            if (numeros[10] != 11 - resultado)
                return false;

        return true;
    }
```

Adicione na página ou no Layout que a página está utilizando referência para os seguintes arquivos de Javascript, que são utilizados para utilizar DataAnnotations:

```
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Além disso, adicione a referência ao arquivo de Javascript criado para fazer a validação no client:

Na classe com as propriedades adicione o nome atributo criado.

```
public class Usuario
{
[Required(ErrorMessage="Nome requerido")]
public string Nome { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage="CPF obrigatório")]
[CustomValidation.CustomValidationCPF(ErrorMessage="CPF inválido")]
public string CPF { get; set; }
}
```

E no formulário os espaços para exibir as mensagens de erro:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.LabelFor(a => a.Nome, "Nome")
@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Nome)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Nome)
<br />

@Html.LabelFor(a => a.CPF, "CPF")
@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.CPF)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.CPF)
<br />

<input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
}
```

Comment: Isso não faz a validação via client, conforme ele citou na pergunta

Comment: Mas com o complemento da resposta abaixo, funciona =D, edite para sua  resposta ficar bem completa, para outros users acharem mais fácil

Comment: Nesse link tem o javascript necessário para fazer a validação no client e o exemplo completo. http://mmaspnetmvc.blogspot.com.br/2014/10/criando-uma-validacao-customizada-para.html

Answer (score 7):

Faço aqui um complemento para a resposta dada pelo @samir-braga, que fará a validação apenas no servidor. Mesmo que o código aparente estar sendo validado no cliente, já que a mensagem de erro será exibida, essa validação é feita no servidor.

Para que ocorra de fato uma validação no cliente, antes de os dados serem submetidos para o servidor, será necessária uma implementação javascript do método `ValidaCPF` além da inclusão desse método no `$.validator` e `$.validator.unobtrusive`, assim:

```
$.validator.addMethod("customvalidationcpf", function (value, element, param) {
    return validaCPF(value); //chama um método validaCPF implementado em javascript
});
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("customvalidationcpf");
```

O nome **customvalidationcpf** deve coincidir com o valor de `ValidationType` declarado no método `GetClientValidationRules`.

Aqui uma implementação de validação de CPF em javascript:

```
function validaCPF(s) {
    var i;
    var l = '';
    for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) if (!isNaN(s.charAt(i))) l += s.charAt(i);
    s = l;
    if (s.length != 11) return false;
    var c = s.substr(0, 9);
    var dv = s.substr(9, 2);
    var d1 = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) d1 += c.charAt(i) * (10 - i);
    if (d1 == 0) return false;
    d1 = 11 - (d1 % 11);
    if (d1 > 9) d1 = 0;
    if (dv.charAt(0) != d1) return false;
    d1 *= 2;
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) d1 += c.charAt(i) * (11 - i)
    d1 = 11 - (d1 % 11);
    if (d1 > 9) d1 = 0;
    if (dv.charAt(1) != d1) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[System.Web.Mvc.Remote("MetodoValidarCPF", "SeuController", ErrorMessage = "CPF inválido.")]
```

E aí você pode criar uma classe só de validações e chamar essa dll no controler e ele reconhecerá

```
public JsonResult ValidarCPF(string cpf = "")
{
   bool validaCPF = SIBValidacoesBLL.ValidarCPF(strCpf);
   return Json(validaCPF, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Se ele retorna true passa na validação, se retorna falso ele barra, você também pode retornar uma mensagem para cada validação, então se ele retorna true passa se retorna string apresenta a string, exemplo

```
return Json("Se não passou na validação retorna uma mensagem customizada", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```